# Is there a way to check if a string contains a Unicode letter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, string, unicode

In Cocoa, regular expressions are presumably following the ICU Unicode rules for character matching and the ICU standard includes character properties such as `\p{L}` for matching all kinds of Unicode letters. However

```
NSString* str = @"A";
NSPredicate* pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '\\p{L}'"];
NSLog(@"%d", [pred evaluateWithObject:str]);
```

doesn't seem to compile:

```
Can't do regex matching, reason: Can't open pattern U_REGEX_BAD_INTERVAL (string A, pattern p{L}, case 0, canon 0)
```

If character properties are not supported (are they?), how else could I check if a string contains a Unicode letter in my iOS app?

Comment: You need to double the backslash - `\\p{L}`, though `MATCHES` requires a full string match. Try `.*\\p{L}.*` or even `(?s).*\\p{L}.*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please take a look at the update.

Comment: Well, I think it works like this: `NSString * rx = @"(?s).*\\p{L}.*";
 NSPredicate * predicat = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", rx];`. Also, just tested `NSPredicate * predicat = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '(?s).*\\p{L}.*'"];`  - [it works](https://ideone.com/MBmFea)

Comment: Also, the code you show [works OK](https://ideone.com/Y5NvO4), just `MATCHES` requires a full string match, and thus, the `h` letter was not enough to return true.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Or `"SELF MATCHES '(?s).*\\\\p{L}.*'"`. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706633/detect-unicode-characters-in-nsstring-on-iphone).

Comment: @AownRaza: I think it is not a dupe of *that* post because here, *any* letter must be detected, regardless of it being from the ASCII range or non-ASCII one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point here is that `MATCHES` requires a full string match, and also, `\` backslash passed to the regex engine should be a *literal* backslash.

The regex can thus be

```
(?s).*\p{L}.*
```

Which means:

- `(?s)` - enable DOTALL mode
- `.*` - match 0 or more any characters
- `\p{L}` - match a Unicode letter
- `.*` - match zero or more characters.

In iOS, just double the backslashes:

```
NSPredicate * predicat = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '(?s).*\\p{L}.*'"];
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/MBmFea)

If the backslashes inside the `NSPrediciate` are treated specifically, use:

```
NSPredicate * predicat = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '(?s).*\\\\p{L}.*'"];
```